# Generate text from a given template

Tags: python, string, random

For example I have a string such as

```
    text = '{Hello|Good morning|Hi}{. We|, we} have a {good |best }offer for you.'
```

How can I generate a set of all possible strings with variants of words in braces?

> Hello. We have a good offer for you.
>
> Good morning, we have a best offer for you.
>
> etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `re` and `random` module, like this:

```
import random
import re

def randomize(match):
    res = match.group(1).split('|')
    random.shuffle(res)
    return res[0]

def random_sentence(tpl):
    return re.sub(r'{(.*?)}', randomize, tpl)

tpl = '{Hello|Good morning|Hi}{. We|, we} have a {good |best }offer for you.'
print(random_sentence(tpl))
```

Comment: But what if text braces have another braces in them? For example
tpl = '{Hello|Good morning|Hi{!|.|!!!}}{ We| we} have a {good |best }offer for you.'

Comment: Since you use the braces as syntax elements, you are adviced to not use braces inside. You might allow for escaped braces, like `{ foo | \{bar\} }`, but in order to evaluate such a string reliably, you need a lexer and a parser. A pure regex, like I've used in my example can't be used for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would use tree-traversal method to get *all* possible variants:

```
import re
text = '{Hello|Good morning|Hi}{. We|, we} have a {good |best }offer for you.'
variants = ['']
elements = re.split(r'([{\|}])',text)

inside = False
options = []
for elem in elements:
    if elem=='{':
        inside = True
        continue
    if not inside:
        variants = [v+elem for v in variants]
    if inside and elem not in '|}':
        options.append(elem)
    if inside and elem=='}':
        variants = [v+opt for opt in options for v in variants]
        options = []
        inside = False

print(*variants,sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
Hello. We have a good offer for you.
Good morning. We have a good offer for you.
Hi. We have a good offer for you.
Hello, we have a good offer for you.
Good morning, we have a good offer for you.
Hi, we have a good offer for you.
Hello. We have a best offer for you.
Good morning. We have a best offer for you.
Hi. We have a best offer for you.
Hello, we have a best offer for you.
Good morning, we have a best offer for you.
Hi, we have a best offer for you.
```

Explanation: I use `re.split` to split str into elements:

```
['', '{', 'Hello', '|', 'Good morning', '|', 'Hi', '}', '', '{', '. We', '|', ', we', '}', ' have a ', '{', 'good ', '|', 'best ', '}', 'offer for you.']
```

Then I create flag `inside` which I will use to store if I am currently inside or outside `{` and `}` and act accordingly.

- If I find `{` I set flag and go to next element (`continue`)
- If I am    not inside brackets I simply add given element to every
  variant.
- If I    am inside and elements is not `{` and is not `|` I    append
  this    element to `options` list.
- If I am inside and find `}`       then I made    variants for every
  possible part of (one of       variants),(one of    options) and
  variants become effect of this       operation.

Note that I assume that: always correct `str` will be given as `text` and `{` will be used solely as control character and `}` will be used solely as control character and `|` inside `{` `}` will be used solely as control character.